# the calendar not appearing in IE and Firefox browsers php code

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, firefox, calendar

I faced issue with my code, I'm using PHP code.
I add calendar to add specific date and this calendar showing in chrome browser but not appearing in IE and Firefox browsers.

thank you

Comment: We need to see some code in order to help you. What is that calendar you added? How did you add it?

Comment: i use this script <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: That comment does not help. The link is not working and is just telling me that you want to use jquery. We need to see your code to know what you are doing wrong. a minimal example that shows the error you get. Lucky you, there is a calendar widget with jQuery. I assume that you mean that widget. There is [a calendar widget example by jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) that seems to work well with firefox.